# select by record from dictionary

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a question about using temp table with about 30 records as search base for select in a table, like a dictionary.

temp table looks something like

```
    VALUES
+----------------+
|   alpha        |  
|   beta         |   
|   gamma        |  
|   omega        |
|   delta        |
|   theta        |
|   rtc. to 30   |
+----------------+
```

Now I have a table

```
 text         varchar          nvarchar
 -----------+----------------+-----------
 28257      |   clarkailey   |   14438
 alpha      |   gamma        |   15023
 2869858    |   nioh         |   beta
```

Now is it possible to search that table and get records that contains values from temp dictionary table?

I have tried something like this

```
select ltrim(rtrim(VALUES)), table.text, table.varchar, table.nvarchar
from #_temp temp
    join table on table.text like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%'
```

It works but only for one column, is there a better way when I want to avoid battle with joins (as maybe later there could be more columns) ?

Comment: `..on table.text like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%' or table.varchar like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%' or table.nvarchar like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%'`

Comment: A query like this would be very slow on larger sets of data. you could try Full Text Search if that is viable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to concatenate all three columns and then perform the join

```
select ltrim(rtrim(VALUES)), table.text, table.varchar, table.nvarchar
  from #_temp temp
  join table on table.text + 'somerandomtext' +
              table.varchar + 'somerandomtext' +
              table.nvarchar
           like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%'
```

The other is to use OR operator:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(VALUES)), table.text, table.varchar, table.nvarchar
  from #_temp temp
  join table on (table.text like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%') OR 
                (table.varchar like '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%') OR
                (table.nvarcharlike '%' + ltrim(rtrim(temp.VALUES)) +'%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query :
        select * from table join temp where concat(text,varchar,nvarchar) like    concat('%',values,'%');